# Программирование на android

Tags: android, ide

Есть ли какие-нибудь приложения на Android, в которых можно писать код, который потом компилируется и запускается? Желательно, чтобы был один из известных языков, но главное, узнать есть ли IDE.

Имеется ввиду, что код набирается в самом смартфоне

Comment: Вы хотите создавать приложения [сидя] под Android? Т.е., скажем, взять планшет с Android и в нем писать/компилировать/запускать?

Comment: Да. Возможно такое?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как ни странно, но это возможно. Вот по крайней мере одна [ссылка](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=191970). Интерпритатор паскаля.

От себя добавлю, что на данный момент ни смартфоны, ни планшеты не позволяют заниматься программированием более-менее серьёзно. Может быть лет через 5-6... Сейчас основное предназначение (тех же планшетов) - потребление контента, а не его генерирование.

Answer (score 4):

SL4A  (понимает lua и Python)

Answer (score 4):

Anjedi отличное IDE для андроида

Answer (score 3):

[C++ compiller for android](https://market.android.com/details?id=GDE.Main&feature=related_apps).

Answer (score 3):

А еще можно и на PyQt Программировать нужно: Py4A, Ministro II или вот ссылка, [Qt для Android (Necessitas Framework) – действительно ли это работает?](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/mobiledev/125845/), тут рассказывают некоторые мелочи.

Есть еще замечательный редактор DroidEdit Pro

Answer (score 2):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui

IDE для разработки под Android.

Answer (score 0):

[DroidDevelop](http://www.assoft.ru/droiddevelop)

Answer (score 0):

Java Compiler, Java Manager. Пишу на Java Compiler, компилирую и запускаю через Java Manager. в PlayMarket-е есть. Прикола ради там пишу, только с библиотеками трудновато...но скоро надеюсь выйдут крутые IDE). А так на ноуте учусь на intellij idea 13